# Using multiple backends with Celery python

Tags: python, celery

I am looking for some help on using Celery with multiple backends. Currently, with the knowledge I have, I can use either RabbitMQ or Redis as the backends but I could not find much information on using both of them as backends at once.

I am looking for something like below

```
app = Celery("tasks", broker="amqp://guest:guest@localhost//", backend1="rpc://", backend2="redis://localhost")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that is not possible. However, nothing stops you from having TWO separate Celery workers, with different configuration. They can, naturally, subscribe to the same queue, or different ones - up to you. If you find a way to do it - please share with us.